# Google Cloud Storage Public Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, storage, acl, public

I have a question about public bucket sharing on my google platform. These are the details:

1 - I applied the public settings (adding AllUsers and AllAuthenticatedUsers to my bucket).
2 - I added some users with ObjectAdmin option so they can upload files.

When I access the bucket with my Google admin user, I can see the "Copy URL" option in the "Public Access" column in the bucket files (shortcut).

[public access shrotcut ok for admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICe7U.png)

This is not the case for public (authenticated or unauthenticated) internet users. For these users, the value "Access granted to public principals" or "Value hidden" appears in the "Public Access" column.

[value hidden but click on file shows public url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQu3R.png)

For the users I added as ObjectAdmin, when opening the file in Public URL, the value "Access granted to public principals" appears

[click on file Public URL Not applicable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrYf.png)

If the access is through any user without ObjectAdmin, I can see the public url when opening the file.

In all scenarios, I can collect the Public URL by clicking the "..." in the file.

Do you know what options I would need to edit or apply (or what roles are needed) in order for the public URL to be displayed as it currently is in the admin user?

This was working last month and I believe it has something to do with Google role updates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with disappearing of "Copy URL" link in a list of files on a storage bucket.

After some time of playing with permissions I've figured out that users having "Storage Object Admin" role on a bucket level need also the "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" role additionally. Then such users can see the link "Copy URL" again.

It looks like Google changed the set of available roles/permissions for cloud storage and automatically granted "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" role to Owners and Editors of the project. But when users added on a bucket level (not via project's IAM) they don't fit to those project roles, even if they are Admins for the bucket.

Comment: Hi AlexJet! Thanks for your note. I created a user and gave him these permissions, the value of "Copy URL" actually appears without having to access the value through the "..." menu, as some users reported (users who do not have this permission), the value "Copy URL" eventually disappeared from view. I asked users to copy the public url of the files using the option in "..." of each file. Does assigning this "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner" setting elevate the user's permissions could cause a problem?